# FutureTask.get method is blocking forever, although I am setting it's value from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to signal between two threads using the below FutureResult class which extends FutureTask class. When run the script, it prints the following result.

SENDING: 0
  SENT: 0
  POLL: FutureResult@513431
  SIGNALLED: FutureResult@513431

Then the program hang up forever. I expect FutureResult instance should return the value from it's blocking get method. Then print the result in the console. But FutureResult.get is blocking forever.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

/**
 * Created by someone on 20/08/2015.
 */
final public class FutureResult<T> extends FutureTask<T> {
    private static final Object SS = "SS";

    public FutureResult() {
        super(() -> null);
    }

    public void signal(final T value) {
        set(value);
    }

    public void signalError(final Throwable throwable) {
        setException(throwable);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        final ArrayBlockingQueue<FutureResult> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000000);
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final FutureResult poll = queue.take();
                    System.out.println("POLL: " + poll);
                    if (poll != null) {
                        poll.signal(SS);
                        System.out.println("SIGNALLED: " + poll);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                final FutureResult<Object> result = new FutureResult<>();
                System.out.println("SENDING: " + i);
                queue.offer(new FutureResult());
                try {
                    System.out.println("SENT: " + i);
                    result.get();
                    System.out.println("GOT : " + i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
queue.offer(new FutureResult());
```

You're setting the value on one `FutureResult`, but that's not the one you're waiting for. Just change that line to:

```
queue.offer(result);
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the confusion is in the use of FutureTask.  FutureTask is designed as a Runnable; running it is necessary.

Honestly, based on the code, it looks like the custom code is implementing something similar to FutureTask.  If the intent here is to learn to use FutureTask, then create a FutureTask instance with a "run" method, and then execute that run method.  On completion of the run method, the FutureTask.get() will complete.